# What to do with "java: No enum constant javax.lang.model.element.Modifier.SEALED" build error?

Tags: java, ssl, rmi

For a University project we need to implement a server 'registrar' that communicates with a client 'barowner' through a SSL RMI connection. When building the client, I get the error java: No enum constant javax.lang.model.element.Modifier.SEALED build error. The Server gets build without any problems.

**BarownerMain.java**

```
package com.example.BarOwner;

import com.example.registrar.RegistrarInterface;

import javax.rmi.ssl.SslRMIClientSocketFactory;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.rmi.NotBoundException;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;

public class BarOwnerMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException {

        String pass = "password";
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.debug", "all");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/keys/raynaud.jks");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", pass);
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/keys/raynaud.jks");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", pass);

        Registry registrarRegistry;
        RegistrarInterface registrarInterface;
        try {
             registrarRegistry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(
                    InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName(), 1112,
                    new RMISSLClientSocketFactory());
            registrarInterface = (RegistrarInterface) registrarRegistry.lookup("RegistrarService");
            BarOwnerMenu.showMenu(registrarInterface);
        } catch (RemoteException | NotBoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

I already tried editing javax.lang.module as desribed in [JDK-8244367](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8244367) but IntelliJ doesn't let me. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like you have a version conflict.

Comment: what is a java version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to change the SDK version to 15, and then return it to the updated version.
You can change your DSK version in the "Project Structure", shortcut to get there:

ctrl+alt+shift+S

["Project Structure" window in IntelliJ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKPUT.png)

Make sure you click the "Apply" button.

It helps me solve the same problem.

Comment: In my case, I was using SDK 11 in the project in IntelliJ.  I had to change it to select SDK 17 from Project Structure -> Project Settings -> Project -> SDK.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the same project by lowering the language level.
From jdk 17+,**sealed types** are introduced.

1)Go to File>>Project structure.
2)Click the **Language level** dropdown and set it to **16**

Close and rebuild your application.Should now work.

Comment: however true, you never downgrade, but instead seek to fix/workaround the current issue

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IntelliJ, find the .iml file in your project

You are looking for this line:

```
<component name="NewModuleRootManager" LANGUAGE_LEVEL="JDK_17">
```

Set language level to 16

```
<component name="NewModuleRootManager" LANGUAGE_LEVEL="JDK_16">
```

Rebuild your project :)