# java: No enum constant javax.lang.model.element.Modifier.SEALED

Tags: java, intellij-idea2017

I upgraded my web project's Java version to 21, and spring boot to 3.X.
now, when I want to build and run Java project by IntelijIDEA, this exception throws.

Comment: It's a compiler error, not an exception. And a weird one at that, considering that `SEALED` [is still there in java 21](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api//java.compiler/javax/lang/model/element/Modifier.html#SEALED).

Comment: And by the way, did you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74674857/what-to-do-with-java-no-enum-constant-javax-lang-model-element-modifier-sealed)?

Comment: You've tagged this with [tag:intellij-idea2017]. Is that saying you're using version 2017 of IntelliJ? If so, what happens if you update IntelliJ to the latest version?